# Importing excel files into rails using RubyXL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, rubyxl

I'm trying to build a simple excel importer using RubyXL in rails to display barcode numbers. What i want to do is import am excel file and display the barcode results on an index page. I'm running into a couple errors and I'm not sure what exactly I'm missing. Here's what I have:

Controller:

```
class BarcodesController < ApplicationController
    
    def index
        @barcodes = Barcode.all
    end

    def show
        @barcode = Barcode.find(params[:id])
    end
    
    def  import
        Barcode.import(params[:file])
        redirect_to @barcode, notice: "Barcode imported"
    end
end
```

Model:

```
class Barcode < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.import(file)
        workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse(params[:file].path)
        worksheets = workbook.worksheets
        puts "Found #{worksheets.count} worksheets"

        worksheets.each do |worksheet|
            puts "Reading: #{worksheet.sheet_name}"
            num_rows = 0
            worksheet.each do |row|
                row_cells = row.cells.map{ |cell| cell.value }
                num_rows += 1
            end
            puts "Read #{num_rows} rows"
        end
    end
end
```

View:

```
<h2>Import Barcodes</h2>

<%= form_tag import_barcodes_path do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users

  resources :barcodes do
    collection { post :import }
  end

  root to: "pages#root"
end
```

Here's the error message:

```
NameError in BarcodesController#import
undefined local variable or method `params' for Barcode(Table doesn't exist):Class
Extracted source (around line #4):
2
3
4
5
6
7
              

    def self.import(file)
        workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse(params[:file].path)
        worksheets = workbook.worksheets
        puts "Found #{worksheets.count} worksheets"
```

Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: `Barcode(Table doesn't exist):Class` looks very suspicious. Are you sure the migration to create the barcodes table was successful?

Answer (score 0):

> undefined local variable or method `params'

This is because it is looking for `params` local variable but it does not exist within `Barcode.import` method.

It's super simple. Pass the `params` from your controller to the `import` method of the `Barcode` model.

1. Change 1

Change the method from `def self.import(file)` to `def self.import(params)`

2. Change 2

In controller, change `Barcode.import(params[:file])` to `Barcode.import(params)`